# Laptop resume with external display: all windows are displaced to other workspaces, why?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, suspend, workspaces

I am not sure if this is the default behavior and if someone else noticed it. Suppose I have 4 workspaces with an external display plugged in so my workspace setup looks like this:

```
[W1a W1b]    [W2a  W2b]    
[W4a W4b]    [W4a  W4b]
```

W1-W4 are the workspaces, broken into a (external display) and b (internal display).

Now I open Windows in

- W1a → window 1
- W4a → WIndow 2
- W4b → Window 3

If I suspend now and resume afterwards, the windows are displaced to other workspaces (not always the same). Mostly it's like:

- window 1 → W1b
- window 2 → W4b
- window 3 → W4b

How can I make them stay where they are before suspend?

Comment: I have this issue too. I don't have an answer, but here is the related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/382056